# Is Pete Duffy based on a specific murderer?

Tags: john-grisham, theodore-boone

In the *Theodore Boone* book series, a primary criminal is Pete Duffy who has committed a murder. Is Pete Duffy based on a specific murderer or is he based on the general trope of a murderer? If he is based on a specific murderer, who is that murderer?

Comment: @fi12 I am mainly looking for what John Grisham did, so if he hasn't said anything on it, the answer could be no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete Duffy is based on a **general trope of a murderer, not a specific criminal**. I haven't been able to find any murderers who murdered their wife for life insurance money, and then could've been sentenced guilty if evidence from an undocumented immigrant was analyzed. In addition, no murderers' first trial (that I've found) ended in a mistrial/retrial.